# Font awesome showing random symbols locally

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I downloaded a popular website template called [academic pages](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io) and run locally using `bundle exec jekyll serve`. Everything seems to work as expected except the font-awesome icons in the sidebar seem to take on random images.

[image]

I deploy that same code online and the icons render as expected.

[image]

Why would this be the case when I haven't changed the code at all?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Hi @Matthias, the link is provided in the question to the repo I am talking about. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: I was refering to your project. A link to your project. I mean i would compare the code inside the browser and see if there is any differences. And also test different browsers. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Oh sorry I understand. This issue occurs before I make any changes to the project, so maybe it is a version issue with font awesome? I'm stumped

Comment: Can you try a newer version of font awesome?

Comment: @Matthias how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because it can't find the fonts; check the path in @font-face and verify that it points to the folder where you saved the fonts.

I checked the fontawesome implementation for SASS and discovered that by default @font-faces are not included in the fontawesome.scss file; modify the file and add them.

```css
@import 'brands';
@import 'regular';
@import 'solid';
```

Comment: But it has too since it works when deployed right? [Here](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io/tree/master/_sass/vendor/font-awesome) is the font awesome folder, can you expand on what needs to be changed?

Comment: I have added these imports to the [`fontawesome.scss`](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io/blob/master/_sass/vendor/font-awesome/fontawesome.scss) file but the error still persists. When I run locally the icons still seem to be randomly selected from the font awesome library.

Comment: I also notice this ['main.css`](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io/blob/master/assets/css/main.scss) file does contain two of those imports (and adding the third doesn't fix things. I'm guessing font-awesome is being imported differently locally vs online. However, I can't find why/where?